# JavaScript equivalent to Java's Charset/String class combination for decoding byte arrays

Tags: java, javascript

In Java, if we know the encoding for a byte array, we can decode it and get the corresponding characters as follows -

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding);
String decodedString = new String(byteArray, charset);
```

How can the same result be achieved in JavaScript?

Suppose I read a file that I know is windows-1253 encoded (Greek). In order to correctly display the file contents, I would have to decode the bytes in the file.

If we do not decode (or open the file in a text editor that doesn't know the encoding), we may see something like this -

```
ÁõôÞ åßíáé ç åëëçíéêÞ.
```

But when this text (i.e. the bytes) is decoded, we get

```
Αυτή είναι η ελληνική.
```

Comment: Not easily, unfortunately.  Node or browser?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a charset you'd want to convert from/to? And what your idea of working with it involves?

Comment: String.fromCharCode.apply( null, arr)

Comment: @crush updated question with example.

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript strings are always UTF-16 encoded. [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
var getString = function (strBytes) {

    var MAX_SIZE = 0x4000;
    var codeUnits = [];
    var highSurrogate;
    var lowSurrogate;
    var index = -1;

    var result = '';

    while (++index < strBytes.length) {
        var codePoint = Number(strBytes[index]);

    if (codePoint === (codePoint & 0x7F)) {


    } else if (0xF0 === (codePoint & 0xF0)) {
        codePoint ^= 0xF0;
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (strBytes[++index] ^ 0x80);
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (strBytes[++index] ^ 0x80);
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (strBytes[++index] ^ 0x80);
    } else if (0xE0 === (codePoint & 0xE0)) {
        codePoint ^= 0xE0;
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (strBytes[++index] ^ 0x80);
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (strBytes[++index] ^ 0x80);
    } else if (0xC0 === (codePoint & 0xC0)) {
        codePoint ^= 0xC0;
        codePoint = (codePoint << 6) | (strBytes[++index] ^ 0x80);
    } 

        if (!isFinite(codePoint) || codePoint < 0 || codePoint > 0x10FFFF || Math.floor(codePoint) != codePoint)
            throw RangeError('Invalid code point: ' + codePoint);

        if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF)
            codeUnits.push(codePoint);
        else {
            codePoint -= 0x10000;
            highSurrogate = (codePoint >> 10) | 0xD800;
            lowSurrogate = (codePoint % 0x400) | 0xDC00;
            codeUnits.push(highSurrogate, lowSurrogate);
        }
        if (index + 1 == strBytes.length || codeUnits.length > MAX_SIZE) {
            result += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, codeUnits);
            codeUnits.length = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

All the best !